# A question about retraction mapping

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation

Let  $f:\overline{B}_r(0)\rightarrow \overline{B}_r(0)\setminus\{0\}$ be a continuous function. Suppose that $f(x)=x$, when $x\in \partial \overline{B}_r(0)$. Then we can consider a continuous function $g:\overline{B}_r(0)\rightarrow \partial\overline{B}_r(0)$ $$g(x)=r\frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}.$$

Clearly $g(x)=x$, when $x\in \partial \overline{B}_r(0)$, and this is in conflict with [the no-retraction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract#No-retraction_theorem) .

**Question**:

Let  $f:\overline{B}_r(p)\rightarrow \overline{B}_r(0)\setminus\{p\}$ be a continuous function. Suppose that $f(x)=x$, when $x\in \partial \overline{B}_r(p)$. Then we can consider a continuous function $g:\overline{B}_r(p)\rightarrow \partial\overline{B}_r(p)$ $$g(x)=r\frac{f(x)-p}{|f(x)-p|}+p.$$

Now it is not at all clear to me that we can conclude a contradiction. Is there any? What might be a remedy or an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the function $f:\overline{B}_r(p)\to\overline{B}_r(p)\setminus\{p\}$, let

$$g:\overline{B}_r(0)\to\overline{B}_r(0)\setminus\{0\}:x\mapsto f(x+p)-p\;,$$

and apply the original result to $g$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, prof. I noticed that on the boundary $\partial\overline{B}_r(p)$ we can write $f(x)=x$ in the form $re^{i \theta}+p$, so indeed $g(x)=x$, and we can apply no-retraction theorem.

Comment: @Juho: You’re welcome.